# Java: How to split on colon for HTTP headers

Tags: java, regex, string, http, header

If I have header name value pair such as:

```
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
:authority: stackoverflow.com
something: some:value
```

How do I only split after the header name? Meaning, following would be my results:

```
accept-encoding => gzip, deflate, br
:authority => stackoverflow.com
something => some:value
```

I have tried `str.Split(":", 2)` but it doesn't handle the :authority header

Answer (score 1):

You can split with `:` that is preceded with a word char and not followed with a word char:

```java
str.split("\\b:\\B")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGE1cv/1). Alternatively, you may split with `:` that is preceded with a non-whitespace char and is followed with a whitespace:

```java
str.split("(?<=\\S):(?=\\s)")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGE1cv/2).

*Details*:

- `\b:\B` - a word boundary (`\b`) requires a letter, digit or `_` to appear immediately to the left of the `:` (as `:` is a non-word char) and the next non-word boundary `\B` requires a non-word char (any char other than letter, digit or underscore) to appear immediately on the right, or end of string can occur there, too
- `(?<=\S)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char
- `(?=\s)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to split on the first occurrence of `:` and allow an optional `:` at the start of the string, you could also make use of a lookbehind with a finite quantifier in Java `{0,n}` where n in this example is 100

```
(?<=^:?[^:\r\n]{0,100}):
```

In Java

```
str.Split("(?<=^:?[^:\\r\\n]{0,100}):")
```

- `(?<=` Postive lookbehind

  - `^:?[^:]{0,100}` From the start of the string, match an optional `:` and 0-n occurrences of any char except `:` or a newline
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `:` Match the colon to split on

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zCqE9q/1)